# How to wait for all pending completion handlers to be executed before stopping io_service?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I'm writing a server using [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). I have multiple threads each owning it's own `io_service` object. I'm using `io_service::work` object to keep `io_service` running when there is no completion handlers to execute. In certain moment I'm calling `stop` method of `io_service` objects to finish threads which called `io_serice::run`. But in some cases when I'm calling `stop` I have posted in `io_service` object competion handlers which are not finished. Calling `stop` prevents posted competion handlers from executing, but this is unacceptable for me because I need all pending work to be finished before stopping the thread. How to wait for all pending completion handlers first to be executed before calling `stop` method of `io_service`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reset the `work`.

Any `io_service::run()` will return when all pending work has been completed.

The common pattern is to use `optional<work>` so you can clear it. If it is a frequent thing, you could reduce some mental overhead by wrapping it in a RAII-enabled class:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2cfbbbc6e278eca0)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

struct work {
    using io_service = boost::asio::io_service;
    work(io_service& svc) : _work(io_service::work(svc)) 
    { }

    void release() {
        _work.reset();
    }

    void enlist(io_service& svc) {
        _work.emplace(io_service::work(svc));
    }

  private:
    boost::optional<io_service::work> _work;
};

#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service svc;
    work lock(svc);

    std::thread background([&] { svc.run(); });

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);

    std::cout << "releasing work";
    lock.release();

    background.join();
}
```

Which finishes the background thread after 1 second.

Comment: How to reset the `work`? I don't see `reset` method of `work` class nor the `io_service` class. Maybe you mean to use dynamically allocated `work` object which to `delete` (or reset `std::unique_ptr<io_service::work>`) when I want to stop?

Comment: @bobeff, "_Maybe you mean to use dynamically allocated work object which to delete_" yes, that is the common pattern. You can use `boost::optional<io_service::work>` as well.

Comment: @bobeff Yes. I added some sample code to the answer.